# Docker: How to deploy a vsftpd instance?

Tags: linux, deployment, ftp, docker, vsftpd

#### Background:

I'm starting to try web deployment on *Docker*.

So now I have now:

1. **mariadb** instance to hold all the data, the data directory is set as volume;
2. **php:fpm** instance for individual websites, which volumes are set to the sub-directories of `/var/docker/www`;
3. **nginx** front-end as a individual container, volume is set to `/var/docker/www`, configuration volume is set as `-v /var/docker/nginx/conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d`;

So, there is one thing left, I want to give a ftp account to relating customers to access the sub-directories of `/var/www`.

For example: `/var/docker/www/site1`, or `/var/docker/www/site2`

---

#### Question

So, now I want to make a vsftpd image myself, but I was facing to the below questions:

1. How should I set the user permissions? I will have different ftp users, but the www file owners are all set to `root`.
2. *(Newbie question)* Should I start the `vsftpd` inside as daemon? Setting `listen=NO`?
3. How to set the network? Will that be a NAT problem?

**Finally**, is there a good overall solution on this problem? To deploy a vsftpd instance on docker host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I will have different ftp users, but the www file owners are all set to root.

It would be best if those www files could be set to www-data, as this [`docker-vsftpd/Dockerfile`](https://github.com/helderco/docker-vsftpd/blob/fd57750a0cd0e899c80dd3e3ca3205512fcf6b9a/Dockerfile#L13) does.
You also have [`fauria/docker-vsftpd`](https://github.com/fauria/docker-vsftpd) which allows to parameterize the ftp user, but that will be useful only if www files are part of a common group with said ftp users.

Comment: But how can I chroot different ftpusers in different dir? `user1` => `www/site1` and `user2` => `www/sizte2`

Comment: Each of these subdirectories should be part of a different group, group common with their respective user.